# Find the index of a clicked field in QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview

In a QTableView, I need to find the index of the field where it is clicked. I have the following method where i want to paste the value from the clipboard by pressing "ctrl+v" in the field of the table that is clicked:

```
    QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+v'),self).activated.connect(self._handlePaste)

     # paste the value  
def _handlePaste(self):
    clipboard_text = QApplication.instance().clipboard().text()
    #item = QTableWidgetItem()
    #item.setText(clipboard_text)
    NvmQtModel.setData(self, index, clipboard_text, Qt.DisplayRole)
    print clipboard_tex
```

Update:

```
    # paste the value  
def _handlePaste(self):
    clipboard_text = QApplication.instance().clipboard().text()
    index = QItemSelectionModel.selectedIndexes()
    NvmQtModel.setData(self, index, clipboard_text, Qt.DisplayRole)
```

Exception:

```
    index = QItemSelectionModel.selectedIndexes()
    TypeError: QItemSelectionModel.selectedIndexes(): first argument of unbound  method  must have type 'QItemSelectionModel'
```

Comment: You'll have to call `selectedIndexes` on the actual instance of the model. You're trying to call it in a static manner. `tableView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()` would be the proper way, where you'll obviously have to replace `tableView` with whatever variable actually holds your QTableView. `NvmQtModel.setData(...)` looks somewhat suspicious as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QAbstractItemView::indexAt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) method is for your question. But I propose you to work with [selection model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) instead of detecting clicks.

Comment: Do u mean something like this ? index = QItemSelectionModel.selectedIndexes()

Comment: Yes. But you should be sure, that multiselection is not enabled. Because selected indexes is array.

Comment: Exception:  
TypeError: QItemSelectionModel.selectedIndexes(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QItemSelectionModel'